# MySQL GROUP BY not giving desired result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to show summary as number of males, number of females in each unit. Tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    unit,
    CASE gender
        WHEN 'Male' THEN COUNT(id)
    END AS 'male',
    CASE
        WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN COUNT(id)
    END AS 'female'
FROM
    admission_info
WHERE
    admission_date = '2017-04-15'
GROUP BY gender
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24c760/1) which shows the output. But i want it in 1 row where it should show unit name, number of males, number of females.

Comment: group by unit, not gender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT unit, 
sum(CASE gender WHEN 'Male' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS 'male', 
sum(CASE WHEN gender='Female' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS 'female' 
FROM admission_info WHERE admission_date='2017-04-15'
group by unit
```

Comment: PERFECT output. Thanks.

Comment: Add GROUP BY unit in the last otherwise it always returns 1 row no matter  unit is A or B.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT unit, gender, count(id) as count
FROM admission_info WHERE admission_date='2017-04-15' GROUP BY unit, gender
```

Comment: It return 2 rows

Comment: Yes, What do you expected ? @sunny93

Comment: All in single line. Unit: A, Male 1, Female 1